# Show that if AB+CD=AD+BC then the quadrilateral $ABCD$ is tangential

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

Consider a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ . Show that the quadrilateral $ABCD$ is tangential if and only:$AB+CD=AD+BC$

Comment: _Hint_: If the circle touches $AB$ at $P$, and $AD$ at $Q$, then $AP=AQ$. (And there are three more such equalities.)

Comment: Yes I do it @TonyK . But I stopped at that point . Please somebody help me.

Comment: You do not accept any of the answers of your questions.you should accept the best one to bring it to first it also gives you reputation.Also use MathJax to improve your questions.Also write your attempt to the question if you don't some people will give it negetive and maybe it puts on hold.

Answer (score 2):

Theorem:We know that in any tangential quadrilateral $ABCD$ we have $AB+CD=AD+BC$

proof:

lemma:The tangents that we draw from a point to a circle is equal.

[image]

because two triangles are equal tangents are equal too.

Using this lemma we can proof this theorem like this picture.

[image]

Now we want to proof the opposite of the theorem:

Think that The theorem holds and $ABCD$ isn't tangential then follow this picture:

[image]

according to the picture $AB'CD$ is tangential then we have:

$c+AB'=d+CB'$also we have $a+c=b+d$ from if we subtract the second one from the first one we have:$BB'=b-CB'$ and then $BB'+CB'=b$.Using the inequality of triangle we can know it never happens because:

[image]

Because the equality is false our assumption is false too.Then we can know $ABCD$ is tangential.

Comment: I don't understand your proof strategy.

Comment: It's clear where can't you understand?

Comment: OK, I see now that you are proving the "if" part. (The "only if" part is rather easy, and follows from my hint to the OP.) But your explanatory text is rather perfunctory.

Comment: Ok will edioted.